# How do I set the updatedAt timestamp using mongoose during a data migration

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am doing a data migration from MS SQL to MongoDB. I am using mongoose and in my schema I set the timestamp property to true.

```
{
  timestamps: true
}
```

I then try and set the values of the createdAt and updatedAt fields. When inserting a record. The createdAt field saves correctly, however, the updatedAt field is set to whatever the createdAt field is.

Is this the standard behaviour or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: How are you saving your records and how your schema looks like can you post here?

Comment: how are you migrating the data? are you using some library to do it?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/73310825/717267

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The timestamps option is really cool, without doubt, but i'm still doing it "old school":

```
'use strict';
/**
 * Module dependencies
 */
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


var DataSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true, 
        lowercase: true
    }, 
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    updated: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

DataSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    this.updated = Date.now();
    return next();
});

mongoose.model('Data', DataSchema);
```

Comment: This will work for me as I can check if the updatedAt field has been set and only automatically set it if not set.

Comment: Hey Soli, it was a long time ago, try to use the built in timestamp manager.

Comment: Note that this will not work if you run update, or findAndUpdate, or basically any other methods of updating.

Answer (score 0):

During your migration, when you set the timestamps on your new records, pass the `timestamps: false` option along with your `save()` or `create()`.

```
await newRecord.save({timestamps: false});
```

This will override the `timestamps: true` setting on the model for this particular save allowing you to use timestamps from your old data without interference.

From [the documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model-save) for this option:

> [options.timestamps=true] «Boolean» if false and timestamps are enabled, skip timestamps for this save().